# Visual Basic check if the file is open | duplicate closed

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way to check if this(example test.xlsm) file is open ?

```
Dim v_datenwb As String
v_datenwb = "test.xlsm"
Dim err As String
err = " ist nicht geöffnet!"
Dim op As Integer
op = 0

Do While op <> 1
If IsFileOpen(v_datenweb) = True Then
Workbooks(v_datenwb).Activate
op = 1
Else
If vbCancel = MsgBox(v_datenwb & err, vbRetryCancel, "Error") Then
    Exit Sub
End If
err = " ist nicht geöffnet! Sind sie sich sicher dass das Dokument offen ist ?"
End If
Loop

Public Function IsFileOpen( _
ByVal FileName As String, _
Optional ByVal ViewKind As String ="{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}" _
) As Boolean
```

I tried somthing like thatt but it didnt worked.
Everytime when the program checked if the file is open the result was False.

I'd appreciate any proposal for a better solution.

Comment: I dont want to have a file path.
Do you have a solution when i dont have a path ? 
@dot.Py

Comment: We can't see your IsFileOpen function, the one that actually matters. Please post the code of that as well.

Comment: I think that is the problem i'm not good at coding and i think the function is missing i thought that was the function.
I got it from this site : https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/aa300915%28v=vs.71%29.aspx @vacip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple logic can be used as below to check if a file is open...

```
Function IsFileOpen(fileName As String) As Boolean
Dim wb As Workbook
On Error Resume Next
Set wb = Workbooks(fileName)
On Error GoTo 0
If Not wb Is Nothing Then IsFileOpen = True
End Function

Sub Test()
Dim fName As String
fName = "test.xlsm"
If IsFileOpen(fName) Then
    MsgBox "File is open.", vbExclamation
Else
    MsgBox "File is not open.", vbExclamation
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You defined `v_datenwb = "test.xlsm"` but you called `v_datenweb` at `If IsFileOpen(v_datenweb) = True Then`.

---

Have you tried [this solution](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/291295/macro-code-to-check-whether-a-file-is-already-open)?

You just have to change `c:\Book2.xls` to your desired workbook.

This code has a function called `IsFileOpen` and a macro called `TestFileOpened` that calls the function.
    Sub TestFileOpened()

```
    ' Test to see if the file is open.
    If IsFileOpen("c:\Book2.xls") Then
        ' Display a message stating the file in use.
        MsgBox "File already in use!"
        '
        ' Add code here to handle case where file is open by another
        ' user.
        '
    Else
        ' Display a message stating the file is not in use.
        MsgBox "File not in use!"
        ' Open the file in Excel.
        Workbooks.Open "c:\Book2.xls"
        '
        ' Add code here to handle case where file is NOT open by another
        ' user.
        '
    End If

End Sub

' This function checks to see if a file is open or not. If the file is
' already open, it returns True. If the file is not open, it returns
' False. Otherwise, a run-time error occurs because there is
' some other problem accessing the file.

Function IsFileOpen(filename As String)
    Dim filenum As Integer, errnum As Integer

    On Error Resume Next   ' Turn error checking off.
    filenum = FreeFile()   ' Get a free file number.
    ' Attempt to open the file and lock it.
    Open filename For Input Lock Read As #filenum
    Close filenum          ' Close the file.
    errnum = Err           ' Save the error number that occurred.
    On Error GoTo 0        ' Turn error checking back on.

    ' Check to see which error occurred.
    Select Case errnum

        ' No error occurred.
        ' File is NOT already open by another user.
        Case 0
         IsFileOpen = False

        ' Error number for "Permission Denied."
        ' File is already opened by another user.
        Case 70
            IsFileOpen = True

        ' Another error occurred.
        Case Else
            Error errnum
    End Select

End Function
```

Comment: Yes and i gto the Error (in german) : Argumenttyp ByRef unverträglich

Comment: How did you implemented it and called the function?  Because I just tested this code here and it worked!